# Removing unwanted rows from sql based on three columns unique ID

Tags: sql, nested, distinct, sql-delete

Here's the code. I'm doing something dumb - what is it? All I get is "syntax error".

```
select 
    code, shortDescription, longDescription, fullDescripton, 
    codeType, useThruDate, updateDate, updateComment, createDate
into 
    #irish
from 
    (select distinct 
         code, shortDescription, longDescription
         when count(code + shortDescription + longDescription) > 1
             then delete from #irish where useThruDate <> '2016-30-06'
              else 0
        )
from [dbo].[irish]
```

---

```
code        shortDescription    longDescription                             fullDescription             codeType    useThruDate     updat‌​eDate    updateComment                   createDate 
312291001   47113               Sample text for a description (from 2012)   NULL                        DB1         2016-30-04      2016-06-06    merged all tables together.     NULL 
312291001   47113               Sample text for a description (from 2012)   Lorem ippsum lorem ippsum   DB1         2016-30-06      2016-06-06    merged all tables together.     NULL 
312291001   47113               Sample text for a description (from 2012)   Lorem ippsum lorem ippsum   DB2         2016-31-05      2016-06-06    merged all tables together.     NULL
```

Comment: Can you add on your question (edit), a little sample data and what would be the result from it?

Comment: They're all varchars, unfortunately.
code = int
shortDescription = int
longDescription =  varchar text- human readable
fullDescription= varchar text- human readable
codeType= short description of the database where it came from
useThruDate is in this format= YYYY-DD-MM
updateDate = YYYY-DD-MM

Comment: Take a look at this answer. See the result from the sql on the answer. What I asked is to you add a little sample data of your problem like that. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38106767/460557

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do??? Looking at the SQL syntax it does not look correct. You are missing the FROM from the nested query. Can you explain what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: code shortDescription longDescription fullDescription codeType useThruDate updateDate updateComment createDate
312291001 47113 Sample text for a description (from 2012)  NULL DB1 2016-30-04 2016-06-06 merged all tables together. NULL
312291001 47113 Sample text for a description (from 2012)  Lorem ippsum lorem ippsum DB1 2016-30-06 2016-06-06 merged all tables together. NULL
312291001 47113 Sample text for a description (from 2012)  Lorem ippsum lorem ippsum DB2 2016-31-05 2016-06-06 merged all tables together. NULL

Comment: Do *not* post code/results in the comments.  Use the [`Edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38106874/edit) button to update your question, instead.

Comment: You have so many things wrong with the code that there is really no place to being -- mixing `select` and `delete`, referring to columns that don't exist, putting aggregation functions in the `where`, using aggregation functions without a `group by`.  You should delete this question and ask another, with sample data and desired results and an explanation of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you were aiming for:

```
/* Creates #irish table */    
CREATE TABLE #irish (
        code NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,shortdescription NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,longdescription NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,fulldescription NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,codeType NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,useThruDate NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,updateDate NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,updateComment NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,createDate NVARCHAR(MAX)
   /* insert select into #irish table */ 
    INSERT INTO #irish

    SELECT DISTINCT
    Code,ShortDescription,LongDescription, fullDescripton, 
        codeType, useThruDate, updateDate, updateComment, createDate
    FROM dbo.irish
    WHERE 
    useThruDate <> '2016-30-06'
    /* My best understanding of your count critera */ 
    AND (code IS NOT NULL
    OR shortdescription IS NOT NULL
    OR longdescription IS NOT NULL)

    /* selects records from #irish table (which we inserted in the last section) */
    SELECT * FROM #irish
    DROP TABLE #irish
```

It's worth noting that using a temp table in this query as it stands has very little benefit, if any.

I hope this helps. There were several issues with your original code (see Gordon's comment), so if you want to dig deeper I would recommend reading a few tutorials. [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp) is a good starting place.